# Pass Secret values/environment var to the flexvol options

Tags: kubernetes, azure-keyvault, azure-aks

I'm trying to use k8s secrets or having environment variables from my local environment to set the flexvol options values, is that possible?

I can see secrets mounted successfully but the flexvol is not able to be mount successfully. Appreciate if there is any different solution other than secrets if any.

The deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: traefik:1.7.7-alpine
        name: traefik
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 80
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: certs 
          mountPath: /certs
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: KV_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: flexvol-var-secret
              key: keyvaultname
        - name: KV_OBJ_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: flexvol-var-secret
              key: keyvaultobjectname
        - name: TENANT_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: flexvol-var-secret
              key: tenantid
        - name: RESOURCE_GROUP
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: flexvol-var-secret
              key: resourcegroup
        - name: SUB_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: flexvol-var-secret
              key: subscriptionid
      volumes:
      - name: certs
        flexVolume:
          driver: "azure/kv"
          secretRef:
            name: kvcreds
          options:
            keyvaultname: ${KV_NAME}
            keyvaultobjectname: ${KV_OBJ_NAME}
            keyvaultobjecttype: "secret"
            tenantid: ${TENANT_ID}
            resourcegroup: ${RESOURCE_GROUP}
            subscriptionid: ${SUB_ID}
```

The secret.yaml

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: flexvol-var-secret
  labels:
    name: flexvol-var-secret
  annotations:
    description: Template for flexVolume variables values
stringData:
  keyvaultname: "###"
  keyvaultobjectname: "###"
  tenantid: ""###"
  resourcegroup: "###"
  subscriptionid: "###"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the same thing and it's not really possible without external tools.

The problem is that flexvolume is only taking the credentials from secret, but rest is considered configuration and needs to be passed in. What you want to do here is essentially variable substitution, which kubernetes does not, and will not support: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787#issuecomment-369645645

On the bright side, you can use any tool to substitute those values with variables from your env variables, from a bash/ps script, up to proper kubernetes deployment solutions like helm.

KV flexvolume is open-source, so could also be modified to handle this use-case

Comment: I found an opened issue in the flexvol repo https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol/issues/28

Comment: That issue is about mounting secrets from keyvault as environment variables within a container, not using kubernetes secret to mount keyvault :)

Comment: :) if you found my answer useful don't forget to upvote and accept